# Como imprimir resultados de un array de una funcion lineal con JavaScript sin utilizar document.write

Tags: javascript, array, botón, matemáticas, innerhtml

Estoy intentado hacer un programa que calcule y=sin(7x-5) en javaScript. Pero cuando imprimo los resultados en el div solo aparece el último valor del array. No quiero usar `document.write` por que quiero que los resultados aparezcan debajo del botón. Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor :(

```html
<body>
                <h1>Funcion Lineal</h1>
                <h3>y = sin(7x-5)</h3>
                Introduce Xmin: <input type="text" id="leerXmin">
                Introduce Xmax: <input type="text" id="leerXmax">
                <button onclick="funcionLineal()">Calcular</button>
                <div id="resultado"></div>
        
    <script>
        function funcionLineal() {
                        var valorXmin = parseInt(document.getElementById("leerXmin").value);
                        var valorXmax = parseInt(document.getElementById("leerXmax").value);
                        var constantA = 7;
                        var constantB = 5;
                        var resultado = [];
        
                        for (let i = valorXmin; i <= valorXmax; i++) {
                            var AxX = constantA*i;
                            var AxXminusB = AxX - constantB;
                            resultado[i] = Math.sin(AxXminusB);
                            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=resultado[i];
                        }
        }
    
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que llevas hasta ahora está muy bien, el problema que tienes es que solo existe un `div` para tus resultados, cada vez que haces:

`document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=resultado[i];`

Estás reescribiendo el valor de ese único `div`.

Hay muchas soluciones para esto, y habrán muchas mejores que la que te voy a dar, pero para que entiendas este concepto te sugiero crear uno por cada nuevo resultado que tengas y agregarlo a tu DOM utilizando `appendChild`, algo así:

```html
<body>
            <h1>Funcion Lineal</h1>
            <h3>y = sin(7x-5)</h3>
            Introduce Xmin: <input type="text" id="leerXmin">
            Introduce Xmax: <input type="text" id="leerXmax">
            <button onclick="funcionLineal()">Calcular</button>
                                         
    
<script>
    function funcionLineal() {
                    var valorXmin = parseInt(document.getElementById("leerXmin").value);
                    var valorXmax = parseInt(document.getElementById("leerXmax").value);
                    var constantA = 7;
                    var constantB = 5;
                    var resultado = [];
    
                    for (let i = valorXmin; i <= valorXmax; i++) {
                        var AxX = constantA*i;
                        var AxXminusB = AxX - constantB;
                        resultado[i] = Math.sin(AxXminusB);
                        let res = document.createElement("div");                      
                        res.innerHTML=resultado[i];                                          
                        document.body.appendChild(res);  
                    }
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Con este nuevo código generas un nuevo `div` cada vez que obtienes un resultado y cambias su html interno de la manera en la que lo estabas intentando hacer.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: :o :o :o !!  siiiii , eso es lo que queria hacer muchisimas muchisimas gracias!!!!! :') llevo todo el dia intentando prometo estudiar mas lo juro